# Getting the fundamental elements of a set of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $B = \{4, 5, 6\}$, and $C = \{A, B\}$. Let's call the elements of $A \cup B$ the *fundamental elements*.

It is easy enough to get the set of fundamental elements from $A$ and $B$ i.e. $\{x \; | \; x \in A \lor x \in B\}$ or even $A \cup B$.

It doesn't seem as straight forward if we want to get the fundamental elements from $C$ though. Perhaps $\{ x \; | \; y \in C \land x \in y \}$?

This requires knowing how many subsets you need to go down before you get to the fundamental elements though. What about if you have an abstract set of subsets where the depth of the subsets until you get to the *fundament* elements is unknown/arbitrary?

Comment: You may be interested in a Wikipedia article on [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement).

Comment: If you work in ZF then, by foundation, you know there are only finitely many stages, so you can use the transitive closure.

Comment: In axiomatic set theory given by ZF (or by GBN), the set $A\cup B$ is actualy derived from the set $C$. The Axiom of Pairing says that given $A$ and $B$, there is a set $C’$ that has $A$ and $B$ as elements (from which, the Axiom of separation allows you to construct the set $C$ whose elements are *exactly* $A$ and $B$). The Axiom of union says that given a set $x$, there is a set $y$ such that $z\in y$ if and only if $\exists w\in x(z\in w)$. So that your set $A\cup B$ is actually derived from your set $C$. That is, $C$ is more “basic” than $A\cup B$ in ZF.

Comment: Thanks @Somos that is very interesting and urelements are definitely what I'm talking about but I couldn't find a reference of how  to find them when the _depth_ of subsets is unknown/arbitrary, can you suggest anything?

Comment: @MacRance to be perfectly honest I don't know if I'm in ZF. I did some set theory many years ago during my undergrad and never looked at it again until now when I think I might be able to define a solution space using set theory. It is important that create sets from subsets from subsets an arbitrary amount of times but it is also import that I can always retrieve the urelements at any point.

Comment: I'm sure I understand you @ArturoMagidin, is that a reply to the previous comment by @MacRance?

Comment: @ojunk... No, I was addressing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question assumes a set theory with [*urelements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) (or *fundamental elements*). Given a set $\,S\,$ we want to find $\,{\scr U}(S),\,$ the set of all the urelements used in the construction of $\,S.\,$ The definition is recursive as follows. If $\,S\,$ is an urelement, then
$\,{\scr U}(S) = S,\,$ or else,
$\,{\scr U}(S) = \bigcup_{x\in S} {\scr U}(x).\,$ With a recursive definition you don't need to know the depth of recursion in advance.

Of course, you need some kind of [axiom of foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) to ensure that the recursion "bottoms out". It is needed to eliminate the possibility of having "sets" such as
$$S_0 := \{S_1\},\, S_1 := \{S_2\},\, \dots,\, S_n := \{S_{n+1}\},\, \dots. \tag{1}$$ Note the similarity to
$$S_1 := \{S_0\},\, S_2 := \{S_1\},\, \dots,\, S_{n+1} := \{S_n\},\, \dots, \tag{2}$$ but they are very different cases when used with $\,{\scr U}(S_n).\,$

Comment: It probably ought to be noted that even if your set theory has urelements, it is by no means given that the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, etc., will be urelements.

Comment: In the context of the question, it is clear that $1,2,3,4,5,6$ are assumed to be urelements.

Comment: Thanks @Somos I only know the basics of set theory but is an axiom of foundation totally necessary? Could you just say ${\scr U }(S) = \cup_{x \in S} {\scr U}(x)$ (until ${\scr U } (x) = x$)? Extending this idea, how about: 

Let $\Gamma$ be the set of all urelements and let 
$$\Phi(S) :=  \{x \; | \; x \in S\}$$
then
$${\scr U } (S) := \{\Phi^n(S) \; | \; \exists n \ge 0 \; : \; x \in \Gamma \; \forall x \in \Phi^n(S) \}?$$

Comment: Sorry if thisis a really silly thing to ask but can I just say "Let ${\scr U}(S)$ be an operator that returns all the urelements that makeup $S$"?

Comment: @ojunk Well, actually you just **did** write it and so, of course, you can write it. Human natural languages are very expressive. Mathematical languages are deliberately more restricted and precise. There are several related complex issues involved. For example, here, what does "makeup" mean? Lipstick?

Answer (score 0):

$\cup$C = $\cup${A,B} = A $\cup$ B
immediately gives the fundamental elements.

Comment: And what about if $C$ has sets of subsets of subsets... of an unknown/arbitrary _depth_ of subsets until the fundamental elements are found?